# Mocking. Pre-setup subsequent method calls returns

Tags: rust, mocking

I am trying to test trait's functionality with the `mockall` crate.

The problem is that I cannot find the crate functionality that allows to predefine some subsequent method returns.

Here is a setup to illustrate, there are two crates, and one calls all methods of the other:

```rust
pub trait Trait1 {
    fn func1(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>;
    fn func2(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>;
}

pub trait Trait2: Trait1 {
    // calls func1 and func2
    fn funcX(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError> {
        self.func1()?; // return OK only if both funcs return OK
        self.func2()?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
pub enum SomeError {
    Err,
}
mock! {
    TestMe {}
    impl Trait1 for TestMe{
        fn func1(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>;
        fn func2(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>;

    }
    impl Trait2 for TestMe{
        fn funcX(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>;
    }
}
```

Suppose I want to test what would be if I would got `func1` with an Error, i.e in this case I expect `funcX` to return Error.
***The problem is, I cannot find any possibility to predefine, that `func1` returns Error.***
Here is an example how it might look..

```rust
let mut mock_moving = Box::new(MockTestMe::new());
mock_moving
    .setup(func1 returns SomeError::Err) // <--- ????? should be like this
    .expect_funcX() // we expect this function to be called
    .times(1)
    .returning(move || SomeError::Err); //because func1 returns Error
mock_moving.funcX(); // calling funcX, expect it to call func1 and func2
```

the only what I allowed to write is something like this:

```rust
let mut mock_moving = Box::new(MockTestMe::new());
mock_moving
    .expect_funcX() // we expect this function to be called
    .times(1)
    .returning(move || SomeError::Err);
mock_moving.funcX(); // of course it returns Error! I pre-defined its output, useless!
```

I wonder is there some way to setup traits method returns in advance, so that I can test trait independently from parent trait methods realisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself.
The problems was that I did not understand how mocking works internally.
Here is solution to my own answer:

```rust
pub trait Trait1 {
    fn func1(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>;
    fn func2(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>;
}

pub trait Trait2: Trait1 {
    // calls func1 and func2
    fn funcX(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError> {
        self.func1()?; // return OK only if both funcs return OK
        self.func2()?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
pub enum SomeError {
    Err,
}
mock! {
    TestMe {}
    impl Trait1 for TestMe{
        fn func1(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>; // mocking this
        fn func2(&self) -> Result<(), SomeError>; // mocking this

    }
    impl Trait2 for TestMe{
        //should be left default because we testing this call
    }
}
```

testbench:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn sometest() {
        let mut mock_moving = Box::new(MockTestMe::new());
        mock_moving
            .expect_func1() 
            .times(1)
            .returning(|| Err(SomeError::Err)); // set output to func1
     mock_moving
            .expect_func2() 
            .times(1)
            .returning(|| Ok(()); //set output to func2

        assert!(mock_moving.funcX().is_err()); // call funcX that calls func1 and func2 with 
                                               //provided output

    }
}
```